# Why does Visual Studio 2012 create content folders for Web API projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I find this odd given that a Web API project should really be a view-less MVC 4 Web API based project. Is there any reason for these projects to contain these files by default? I would like to eliminate them all (*.js, *.css, etc.), any reason not to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These files are included to build the "normal browser" view, this is the page wich you see if you navigate to your host without the "/api" call in your url

You could remove these files if you don't want to use their functionality.